# How can I use input function to fill the parameters?

Tags: python-3.x

Create a function called computepay which takes two parameters (hours and rate ).
Enter Hours: 45
Enter Rate: 10
Pay: 475.0

This is my code, but it doesn't show an input dialog when I run the program.

```
  def computepay(x, y):
      x = input('Enter Hours: ')
      y = input('Enter Rate: ')
      if int(x) <= 40 :
        print('\nPay: ' + int(x) * int(y))
      else :
        print('\nPay: ' + 40 * int(y) + ((int(x) - 40) * 15))
```

Comment: Input dialog as in, you don't see `Enter Hours` and `Enter Rate` in your terminal? And don't make a method which accepts `x, y` as arguments, cos these are local variables, so make the method like this: `computePay()` only

Comment: Did you call the function ? and what do you mean by input dialog ?

Comment: @Alok yes! what I want to do is to assign an integer to parameters x and y by input function. Is that even possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: @DaleAndaya , let us know which of the answer worked out for you. In Stackoverflow, we confirm this by marking the answer, and upvoting it, so that people who will come looking out for answer would find the answer which helped you the most and get benefited. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do like this and let me know if that works out for you Dale

```
def computepay():
  x = int(input('Enter Hours: ')) #this is the way to get int input
  y = int(input('Enter Rate: ')) 
  if x <= 40 :
    basicCompute = x * y
    #use f-string instead, it is clean and correct, the way you were doing things with the print was wrong
    print(f'\nPay: {basicCompute}') 
  else :
    # have a variable which computes that for you, don't do that in your print directly
    compute = (40 * y) + ((x - 40) * 15)
    print(f'\nPay: {compute}')
 
# this is how you call your method       
computepay()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
# this is how you get the thing in your terminal, tested and verified
Enter Hours: 30
Enter Rate: 10
Pay: 300
```

**ALTERNATIVE**

If you want your method to accept the two arguments, then `do not do input() inside your method`

```
def computepay(x, y):
  # use x and ye with the arguments only
  if x <= 40 :
    basicCompute = x * y
    print(f'\nPay: {basicCompute}') 
  else :
    compute = (40 * y) + ((x - 40) * 15)
    print(f'\nPay: {compute}')


# When you call your method, before that you have to accept x and y params, then
# pass it to your method
hours = int(input('Enter Hours: '))
rate = int(input('Enter Rate: '))

# then pass it to your method
# this will do the call, and print the data in your console
computepay(hours, rate)
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just call the `function with zero` or `empty string` or even you can `pre define` in it, now you can get the input dialog in whatever ide you are using

```
def computepay(x=0, y=0):
    x = input('Enter Hours: ')
    y = input('Enter Rate: ')
    if int(x) <= 40 :
        print('\nPay: ' + str(int(x) * int(y)))
    else :
        print('\nPay: ' +str( 40 * int(y) + ((int(x) - 40) * 15)))
computepay()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call that function below.

computepay(parameterA,parameterB)

Mind the indentation issues!

Comment: We need more explanation. Please, clarify your solution.